# Custom Adapter to Use Multiple Views in ListView based off of JSON data

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am having trouble creating a Custom Adapter that will allow me to use several different views in a ListView depending on the results from JSON data.

The JSON has 5 different types of data fields and each one needs to have a separate layout.  For example, the "text" field needs a TextView and then a EditText element and the "bool" field needs a TextView and a Switch element.

The JSON data could include any variation of the 5 data fields so I can't create a static layout.

I have created a separate xml file for each type of data field.

Below is the current state of my Custom Adapter with some JSON hard coded into it.

Thanks in advance!

```
public class JobAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private static final String JSON_STRING = "{\"title\":\"Unity Gain Amp install\",\"submit\":\"http://dci-services.decisiveinc.net/ampinstall/\n" +
        "\n" +
        "Submit\",\"sections\":[{\"title\":\"Unity Gain Amp \n" +
        "\n" +
        "Install\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"TechNumber\",\"type\":\"number\",\"label\":\"Tech \n" +
        "\n" +
        "Number\",\"required\":true,\"stored\":true},{\"name\":\"AmpSerial\",\"type\":\"string\",\"label\":\"Amp Serial \n" +
        "\n" +
        "#\",\"required\":true,\"stored\":false},{\"name\":\"Account\",\"type\":\"number\",\"label\":\"Account \n" +
        "\n" +
        "#\",\"required\":true,\"stored\":false}]},{\"title\":\"Reason For Amp \n" +
        "\n" +
        "Install\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"Reason\",\"type\":\"select\",\"label\":\"Reason\",\"required\":true,\"stored\":f\n" +
        "\n" +
        "alse,\"options\":[{\"key\":\"1\",\"label\":\"Low receive power\"},{\"key\":\"2\",\"label\":\"High \n" +
        "\n" +
        "Transmit \"},{\"key\":\"3\",\"label\":\"Both\"},{\"key\":\"4\",\"label\":\"Replacement\"}\n" +
        "\n" +
        "]},{\"name\":\"OldAmpSN\",\"type\":\"string\",\"label\":\"If Replacement: Old Amp \n" +
        "\n" +
        "SN\",\"required\":false,\"stored\":false}]}]}";

int resource;
String response;
Context context;
//Initialize Adapter
public JobAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LinearLayout jobView;
    //Get the current job object
    String job = getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null) {
        jobView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, jobView, true);
    }
    else
    {
        jobView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }
    TextView job_title = (TextView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_title);
    TextView text_title = (TextView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_text_title);
    EditText text_input = (EditText)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_text_input);
    TextView select_title = (TextView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_select_title);
    Spinner select_array = (Spinner) jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_select_spinner);
    TextView location_title = (TextView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_loc_title);
    TextView location_text = (TextView) jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_loc_text);
    TextView image_title = (TextView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_image_title);
    ImageView image_view = (ImageView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_image_thumb);
    TextView bool_title = (TextView)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_bool_title);
    Switch bool_switch = (Switch)jobView.findViewById(R.id.job_bool_switch);

    try {
        JSONObject sections =
                (new JSONObject(JSON_STRING)).getJSONObject("sections");
        String jobtitle = sections.getString("title");
        job_title.setText(jobtitle);

        JSONObject fields =
                (new JSONObject(JSON_STRING)).getJSONObject("sections").getJSONObject("fields");

        JSONArray select_options =
                (new JSONObject(JSON_STRING)).getJSONObject("sections")
                        .getJSONObject("fields").getJSONArray("options");

        if (fields.getString("type").equals("number")) {
            String labelnumber = fields.getString("label");
            text_title.setText(labelnumber);
        }
        if (fields.getString("type").equals("string")) {
            String labelstring = fields.getString("label");
            text_title.setText(labelstring);
        }
        if (fields.getString("type").equals("textarea")) {
            String labeltextarea = fields.getString("label");
            text_title.setText(labeltextarea);
        }
        if (fields.getString("type").equals("bool")) {
            String labelbool = fields.getString("label");
            bool_title.setText(labelbool);
        }
        if (fields.getString("type").equals("select")) {
            String labelselect = fields.getString("label");
            select_title.setText(labelselect);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter.add("Select a Reason");

            for (int i = 0; i < select_options.length(); ++i)
            {
                adapter.add(select_options.getJSONObject(i).getString("label"));
            }
            select_array.setAdapter(adapter);
            select_array.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View itemSelected, int itemkey, long l) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = jobData.edit();
                editor.putInt(reason_data, itemkey);
                editor.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
            });

        }
        if (fields.getString("type").equals("image")) {
            String labelimage = fields.getString("label");
            image_title.setText(labelimage);
        }
        if (fields.getString("type").equals("location")) {
            String labellocation = fields.getString("label");
            location_title.setText(labellocation);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jobView;
}

    }
```

Comment: You have to depend on the **getItemViewType** and **getViewTypeCount** of the [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) class. See this [post](http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row

Comment: I understand the steps required to make a custom adapter allow for multiple layouts in a ListView.  And I also understand how to parse JSON into a ListView.  Where I find myself struggling is using the JSON "Type" field to determine which of the layouts to use for the ListView.  Any help is really appreciated.